# What is correct antenna connection for this Intel tri-band card?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am replacing the Intel 18260ngw tri-band Wlan card on my Latitude 5470. I have hooked the white and black antenna leads to the appropriate posts, however there is a third post (labeled IFCON 4) and not sure which of the remaining 3 leads to attach (brown...black w/gray stripe...white w/gray stripe.
I have been unable to track the solution down using all available resources. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the cables.. if you've already re-connected 1 and 2... how come you've got 3 extra? The Intel 18260ngw only has (from what I've seen) 3 antenna connections...

Comment: I don't currently have access to this laptop, however, it was my impression that the other two cables would connect to an WWAN card, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's for connecting an Intel WiGig antenna.**

[image]